# html_read() creates text duplicates even after removing "span"

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, duplicates, rvest

so I have run into a bit of an issue with webscraping. I have a page I want to extract the text from. My code looks basically like this:

```
url = read_html("linkgoeshere")

url %>%
  html_elements("td") -> td

for (chr in td){
  if (grepl("span", chr)==FALSE){
    list3 = append(list3, chr)
  }
}

# Just as an example how I read out the text

txt = html_text(td)
```

What it starts doing is it gives me the text. But not only the text, but a version with an \n before it, like this. I have placed "text" where the text I am interested in goes:

```
\n\n20W\n\n\n\n\n\nExport\nExport\ntext

\n\n\n\nExport\nExport\ntext

\n\nExport\nExport\ntext
```

and so on until there is finally one that yields just the text I am interest in. The thing is I need to extract the text from about 18000 pages which are similarly constructed, yet the text is not always in the same place so I cannot simply use `txt = html_text(td[u])`.

What I have tried I have basically described above. Any ways to get around this issue? As a note, the information I am interested in are in some what seem to be nested html tables. I have removed any span objects which seemed to cause this issue for other people but to no avail.

KR

Comment: You can go way further with CSS selectors and XPath than just selecting all `td` elements, but without any example data, it is quite difficult to provide any meaningful answers. If you don't want to share the actual URL, perhaps a section from the target HTML document or generate something that is close enough to your actual problem (ChatGPT might be helpful here if you are not into writing HTML from scratch).  And `rvest` already comes with a decent html table parser, `rvest::html_table()`, might not be suitable in all scenarios, but if it works for you, it can save a lot of time.